# How to can I combine two python file to run as one?

Tags: python, function, program-entry-point

I have two different python file that is running okay. All I want is to run them as one.

app.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from importlib import import_module
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, 
Response

# import camera driver
if os.environ.get('CAMERA'):
    Camera = import_module('camera_' + 
os.environ['CAMERA']).Camera
else:
#from camera import Camera
# Raspberry Pi camera module (requires 
picamera package)
    from camera_pi import Camera

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    """Video streaming home page."""
    return render_template('index.html')


def gen(camera):
    """Video streaming generator 
function."""
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: 
image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')


@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    """Video streaming route. Put this in 
the src attribute of an img tag."""
    return Response(gen(Camera()),
                    mimetype='multipart/x- 
mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', threaded=True)
```

This code is from internet, I want is to add my code in here so that when i run this it will also run my code. This is my code.

beam.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", 
"raspberry", "cribdb")

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.IN) #Right level-1


last_status = None

while True:
    input12 = GPIO.input(12)


    if (input12 == 1):
        status = "Lying down"
    else:
        status = "Out of the crib"

    time.sleep(1)

    if status != last_status:
        print(status)
        last_status = status
        curs = db.cursor()
        curs.execute(
        """INSERT INTO tbstatus values(NULL, %s)""", (status,)
)
    db.commit()

    number_of_rows= curs.execute("SELECT * FROM tbstatus")

    if (number_of_rows >= 2):
        curs.execute("""DELETE FROM tbstatus order by id LIMIT 1""")
        db.commit()
```

Is it possible to run them at the same time? I tried to run them both in two different terminal and its working. I just want them to run as a one python file.

Comment: You can make a new python file and import `app.py` and `beam.py` as modules in that file.

Comment: How can I make that? I'm sorry, I'm new to this. Thankyou

Comment: I tried to do it. I created main.py then I imported the two py file. But only the beam.py is working

Comment: Do you have both files located in a single working directory?

Comment: yes they are in same folder. My concern is the app.py file because i think the last line of it have something to do why my main.py only execute the beam.py

Comment: Right. In that case you can simply paste the whole code of `beam.py` to `app.py` and then run it, leaving `__main__ == '__main__'` line but if you want both files to work at the same time then you will have to modify `beam.py` as well to include code to run both programs simultaneously.

Comment: Yes, I like them to run at the same time. Can you help how to modify my beam.py file? Sorry for the disturb. Thank you

Comment: If you want to processes to run at the same time, and be able to share some data and state, you will have to use proper [multithreading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), or write a third module with an appropriate "main" function. If state does not need to be shared, use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process), or better just run both scripts side by side without any change.

Comment: Okay sir. Noted. Thankyou